# Content list empty to Administrator

Tags: 7, nodes

Using Drupal7, I am logged in as administrator, and I am getting an empty content list, even if  there are many nodes created by the administrator user before this.

Even if I add nodes as administrator, the list is still empty.

> [image: screenshot]

Here is the content view configuration's screen

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Best guesses is that it's a cache issue or permission issue. Maybe you have some permission setup that allows admin to see the content page but not the actual content. This shouldn't be possible in vanilla Drupal 8

Comment: But if I access `admin/content/node` then I can able to see the list, the list is empty for `admin/content`

Comment: Is this about Drupa 8 or Drupal 7? Looks more like it's a 7, judging from the screenshot. @DevidasKadam : Can you clarify? And also, whether you are using the Administration Views module? (see answer from kiamlaluno below). Please, update your question accordingly.

Comment: updated question, this is drupal7

Comment: Great. This still requires lots of guessing, kiamlaluno is working hard in his answer below. @DevidasKadam : Could you provide a screenshot of the admin/content View configuration screen where we can see what filters or advanced settings (e.g. relations) are in effect?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I have updated with admin/content View configuration screen

Comment: A few more guesses(after checking the views config): Can you check the author (uid) property of one of the nodes you would expect to appear in this list? Can you check if the relationship "Content: Author" is marked as required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the screenshot you show, it's clear that you installed and enabled the [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module. In fact, for a fresh Drupal 7 installation, the admin/content page would appear as in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

I installed it on my test, and it works fine for me.

> [image: screenshot]

Once you install and enable the module, that administrative page is replaced from a view. If you changed the view, it could be it is filtering out the nodes to show in that page.
Go to admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_node/edit and check the filter criteria aren't too much restrictive. By default, that view has only exposed filter criteria; if you find any not-exposed criterium, that is something manually added to the view, and it could be causing the issue you are seeing. A filter for the content type can cause what you see, but so a filter for the creation date, and many other filters.

As reference, this is the setting page for the view as it comes after installing the *Administration Views* module.

> [image: screenshot]

Also, the view has a setting for caching it (as any view); if it has been changing from *None* to *Time-based*, then either the query results or the render output could be cached for too long. The default values are *1 hour* for both.

> [image: screenshot]

The other reason could be that the view is being filtered by the author name. If I put three spaces in the *Author* field, and then I click *Apply*, I get the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Now the list says *No content available.* even if I still have those two nodes you saw in the previous screenshot. That is because the author name doesn't contain three spaces.
The same happens if I enter three spaces in the *Title* field.

To be sure the exposed filter criteria aren't causing any issue, click on the *Reset* button right to the right of the *Apply* button. That will reset the values for those filters.

Comment: Removed filters, there are only `title,type,published` filters, changed `caching: time-based | 1 hour/1 hour`. still showing empty list

Comment: removed author filter.

Comment: Notice that I was not suggesting to change the cache to _Time-based_. I was just saying that a cache set to _Time-based_ could cause the view to be cached for too long, which means the view could not be updated to the recent changes. Since you don't say which is that setting for the view, and when those nodes were created (e.g. a year ago), I could not exclude that was the reason you could not see any node.

Comment: Also, I am not suggesting to remove filters, but to see if there is any entered value for those exposed filters.

Comment: I am getting content list after disabling [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module.

Comment: it just means the view could filter too much. The default admin/content page doesn't use any view, so it cannot filter too much.